# ExcelWriter and merged cells

Tags: pandas

Good afternoon.Faced with such a problem.

It is necessary to replace the value in Excel by the conditions and save the formatting.
If there are merged cells on the page, then the code throws an error (AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only)
If there are no merged cells, then it works fine

```
node_2 = pd.read_excel('ttt1.xlsx')
node_2.iloc[0,2] = 'NO'
node_2.iloc[2,2] = 'YES'
with pd.ExcelWriter('ttt1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl',mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:

    node_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Лист1',index=False,header=True)
```

[need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wImZP.png)
[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCQxF.png)

If you delete the merged cells, everything works fine.
But I would like it to work with them. Only such a problem